# Creating a single page web app as part of a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server-side

I am working on a project which allows users to monitor energy consumption. The main dashboard page is a web app which is pretty neat and makes extensive use of javascript and ajax. The server currently runs apache and uses php; however, I am planning on installing node.js and updating the server side scripts in order to support websockets (and I also like the idea of using javascript on the server and client side).

I have followed several online introductions but I am struggling to find answers to specific questions, one of which is outlined below.

All guides to node seem to only support single page web apps. This is an issue as there are a number of different pages which require files to be served. How can I support file serving but enable one of the pages to use websockets. Does this functionality, which is only required for one page, need to be coded into the main server script on the site or is there a way of separating this so that the server goes to server the dashboard html file and then discovers that the file requires specific websocket dependencies?

*Thank you very much for taking the time to read my questions. If you can answer any of them, or even provide any general advice, it would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: One question per post, please. Most of these seem to be off-topic though.

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky, but sounds like you should work with node first before diving into this project with it, try out express.js and its templating, etc.

Comment: @Juhana okay, I have cut it down to one question. I don't fully appreciate how this is off-topic

Comment: @7zark7 I would normally agree but due to considerable time pressures, I don't have time to start going down a path of developing the app in ndoe and then suddenly realising that I can't develop the app that way and having to redo everything in PHP. I though it made more sense, to figure out if I could do what I needed to do this way first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: The only reason the guides do single page web apps is because that's node's forte.  Node.js serves static files and rendered templates just fine.  Just include the JS for the websockets only in the pages that need it.

2: It's not quite as simple as with php, but take a look at express.js

3: Yes, and really you shouldn't even need different ports, you can write a proxy in node in one line.

4: CentOS is fine, node is platform agnostic. All the linuxes have top support followed by osx, solaris and windows.

Comment: Awesome, not exactly comprehensive but certainly to the point. Thanks

Comment: For 3, how does a proxy help me?

Comment: You can put node.js on a public port, apache on a private port and have node.js proxy requests to apache as needed.